# jquery - reset button with `change` radio event

Tags: jquery

I using radio buttons and need to listen on the change event like this :

```
   <input type='radio' name='test' value='1' checked /> radio1
   <input type='radio' name='test' value='2'/> radio2
   ....
   <button type='reset' /> Reset </button >
```

And In js:

```
 $('.disp_method input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function () {
        if($(this).val() == 1) {
        alert("change to 1")
        } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
         alert('change to 2')
        }
    })
})
```

When I click on button , the above js function work fine , 
but when I click radio2 and click reset button ,the radio can be reset to original state (radio1 selected) but the above event listening not work,it seem that can not listen `change` event when click reset

Please tell me what wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are all the elements in a `form` tag?

Comment: If <form> tag is used reset should work. Btw, you have syntax error in jquery, check it... Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tu9g08w4/

Comment: Sorry , I mean reset work well ,but It can not alert anything when the radio is change by reset

Comment: JQuery `on()` method doesn't need to `each`. Write your target element in selector of `on()`. See https://jsfiddle.net/2nbf2ub8/

Comment: If you want alert on reset button click... something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tu9g08w4/2/ p.s. As Mohammad said, you don't need each() in this case....

Comment: Sorry for my explain not clear , I mean my function (on change) was trigger by reset button